# Python: Difference between context’s `selectable_objects` and `visible_objects`?

Tags: python

What is the difference between `selectable_objects` and `visible_objects` context members in python API?

And which one should I use in which cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These flags match the 'selectable' and 'visible' states of objects (also shown e.g. in the outliner, in the left columns).

`selectable_objects` is a subset of `visible objects`, since no hidden object shall ever be selectable.

Note also that objects on hidden layers are also considered hidden (i.e. are not in `visible objects`, even if their own visible flag is ON).

As for the last part of your question… it depends on what you want to do! Please be more specific.